# Is 2 pipes more expensive than 1 socketpair?

Tags: pipe, socket, file-descriptors, unix-sockets

Suppose I want to launch a co-process and attach its standard input and output to the main process, what we have here are 2 options:

1. call `pipe(2)` and create 2 pipes, and attach them separately to the standard input and output of the co-process.
2. call `socketpair(2)` and attach 1 end of the socket to the standard input and output of the co-process.

It's well-known that a simple pipe can be implemented more efficiently than a "socket pair", and that's what many systems are doing nowadays. But what if we need it to work in both directions? Is a "pipe pair" still more efficient than a socket-pair?

**Context**

I want to write standard-conforming codes to the best of my effort, therefore the target platform is assumed to be "POSIX-in-general". What I intend to mean with this is that, this question asks for a comparison of the general implementation techniques for the 2 types of IPC as deployed on major implementations, including Linux, {Free,Net,Open}BSD(s), some SVR4 descendants such as Solaris 11.4, etc.

Also, by expensive, I mean more than just IO throughput - system resource consumption is also among my concerns.

Comment: Any reference for socketpairs being less efficient than pipe? Note that ksh93's pipes use socketpair() (though shutdown the reverse direction) instead of pipe() on Linux. Its coprocs also use socket pairs, but two of them. Also note that pipes are bidirectional on many systems (not Linux though)

Comment: FWIW, I get higher throughput on current Debian sid with `ksh93 -c 'cat /dev/zero | pv > /dev/null'` (which uses socketpair()) than with `bash -c 'cat /dev/zero | pv > /dev/null'` (which uses pipe()), even though `pv` uses `splice()` for pipes and read()+write() for sockets

Comment: *The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System* says that their developer used separate constructs for pipes and socketpair(2)

Comment: Quote from page 40: *In systems before 4.2BSD, pipes were implemented using the filesystem; when sockets were introduced in 4.2BSD, pipes were reimplemented as sockets. For performance reasons, FreeBSD no longer uses sockets to implement pipes and fifos. Rather, it uses a separate implementation optimized for local communication.*

Comment: Is your question about FreeBSD specifically? Note that 4.2BSD was released almost 40 years ago, things will likely have changed since, and you'll find a lot of difference between different systems. In the end, it's going to be some FIFO queue handling.

Comment: FWIW, the throughput difference in my examples above are even greater on FreeBSD (12.2 in my test), and still in favour of ksh93 / socketpairs. Twice as much throughput with socket pairs though a lot less than on Linux, though that's a single CPU VM.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas POSIX in general actually. I've updated my question with some context, hope it can be less confusing.

Comment: "It's well-known that..." [citation needed] Anyway, if you're expecting performance issues at that level, you might want to test it anyway on your particular system. I wouldn't be surprised if there were differences there between the various OSes.

Comment: plus the question about what it is you actually want to measure. Two unidirectional pipes would be 2+2 file descriptors, vs. 1+1 one for one bidirectional socket pair, so there's one difference in resource consumption. Plus any possible related overhead wrt. managing the fds, including developer overhead.

Comment: Ah, citation needed, how very quintessential of Wikipedians. I did gave a reference to the FreeBSD book in the comment. And yes, the number of open file descriptions and the amount of resource backing matters. I'm looking for someone to provide a mind-openning insight on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If portability is desired, then at least 2 pipes must be created. This corresponds to 2 open file description compared to 1 as is the case with a socket.

Although not a performance/efficiency reason, you cannot use `MSG_PEEK` with pipes, but you can use it with anonymous sockets, like those created with `socketpair(2)`.